Dagster: Connect assets with operations to validate data model
I recently discovered dagster as an alternative of airflow and I really like it. Great job from the team.
However, I am looking for some help regarding a problem I am facing.
I have several assets responsible to retrieve data from APIs, HTML chart & datasets.
On the current step of the project, I want to add data validator to ensure my data is correct, before using IO Manager to update my data warehouse.
My idea is to use Pydantic BaseModel:
class DataModel(BaseModel):
    name: str

    @validator('name')
    def validate_name(cls, v):
        if v: #whatever you want
            raise ValueError
        return v

In my dagster project, I am currently only using assets and I want to add intermediary step between asset (using dagster Op?) to validate the data.
from dagster import asset, op
import pandas as pd

@asset
def data_asset():
    "Retrieving stage"
    return pd.read_html("")


@asset
def aggregated_asset(data_asset):
    "Aggregation stage"
    return data_asset.apply()

@op
def data_model():
    from module import DataModel
    # do something to validate data asset?

Does it seems you a good idea? How to properly do it, I want my operation op to be in between data_asset and aggregated_asset?
More over, my asset outputs are pandas DataFrame, and I was wondering how I can properly validate all the columns instead of doing row validation through Pydantic validator.
Thank you a lot!
